# How to rename WSL2 docker-desktop node in docker swarm

Tags: windows, docker, docker-desktop, swarm

In the example below I am operating with two nodes in a docker swarm.
The first node is a Linux node that shows the expected node name "myNode-001" while the second node is a windows 10 PC showing the generic node name "docker-desktop".

How can I change the docker node name of the Windows 10 docker-desktop node (to e.g. "myNode-002" or my PC name DESKTOP-XXXXXXX)?

```
$ docker service ps helloworld
    ID                  NAME                IMAGE               NODE                   DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE            ERROR               PORTS
    v4djpoxgo5b9        helloworld.1        alpine:latest       myNode-001             Running             Running 10 minutes ago                       
    50c69xw4tmod        helloworld.2        alpine:latest       docker-desktop <===    Running             Running 2 minutes ago
```

Logging into the docker-desktop distro `$> wsl -d docker-dektop` and running `$> hostname` yields my Windows PC name DESKTOP-XXXXXXX. Apparently docker-desktop inherits my Windows PC hostname as expected.

Running `$> docker system info` in a command shell on my Windows PC yields several properties. One of them is `Name: docker-desktop`. This is the same name as which shows up in my node list on the swarm master. It is also the same name used by for the WSL2 docker-desktop repo.

It may look like that the swarm node name is actually taken from the docker-desktop repo name and not from the docker-desktop repo hostname.

```
$> wsl -l
Windows Subsystem for Linux Distributions:
docker-desktop-data (default)
docker-desktop
```

Not sure if this is a bug or a feature. The goal is still the same: to discriminate between multiple docker-desktops when perusing nodes on the swarm master. Hard to do when they all are showing with the same node name.